# Stackato not servering Django static files

Tags: django, stackato

I am deploying an Django app to Stackato. Everything works fine except static files. According to the documentation, here is my setting in .yml file:

```
processes:
  web: $STACKATO_UWSGI --static-map /static=$HOME/static
```

And here is my local setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

Also, here is my project structure

```
Project -- .....
           |
            static -- css
                  |
                   -- images
```

I did not see any error from the log. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out:

1.While settings.DEBUG is set to True, static url pattern has to be included:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

2.Static files should follow this structure:

```
Project -- <app 'Project'> -- settings.py
           |                  |
           |                  -- urls.py
           |                  |
           |                  -- wsgi.py
           |
           -- <app 'somename'> -- ..
                            |
                            -- static -- <app 'somename'> -- css - a.css
                                                          |
                                                          -- images - a.jpg
```

3.`STATIC_ROOT` should not be the actual location of static directory, which could be as this: `Project/Project/static`, while `STATICFILES_DIRS` has to be the actual static files directory which is `Project/somename app/static`

Reference: https://github.com/mozilla/mozmoderator

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should work. Specifically assets in your *static/css* and *static/images* directories will be available via urls like http://your-stackato-host/static/css/yourstyle.css.

To help troubleshoot this I created a [bare-bones example on github](https://github.com/bcferrycoder/static-wsgi-example.git) which you can clone and push to Stackato to verify it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now by adding missing url settings as posted in the answer.